# problem with my zoomIn or ZoomOu

Tags: qgis, api, c++, zoom

i am using qgis 2.8.2 and qt4.8.5
i have a problem when i call zoomIn or ZoomOut, the raster on canvas is reduce or zoomed but :
- the raster size change
- it disaprar
- it appear again but 3 to 5 seconds later

i don't understand why there is this delay, it seems that there is 2 rendering of the mapcanvas

here is my code :

```
void CMyQgsS57::SlotzoomIn()
{
    ((CMyQgsMapCanvas*)mpMapCanvas)->zoomIn();
}

void CMyQgsS57::zoomIn()    //+
{
    if (((CMyQgsMapCanvas*)mpMapCanvas)->isDrawing() == true) {
      QTimer::singleShot(5, this, SLOT(SlotzoomIn()));
      }
}


void CMyQgsS57::SlotzoomOut()
{
    ((CMyQgsMapCanvas*)mpMapCanvas)->zoomOut();
}

void CMyQgsS57::zoomOut()   //-
{
    if (((CMyQgsMapCanvas*)mpMapCanvas)->isDrawing() == true){
        QTimer::singleShot(5, this, SLOT(SlotzoomOut()));
    }
 }
```

if you have any idea please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem
in my code i have a class for the canvas and a master class that call function or method in the canvas class
the problem is that in the master class there is not the WheelMouseEvent so 
the function of master class and the canvas was in conflict and  generate delay

so i move the code in the canvas class for the zoomin and zommout, because the wheelevent protected member function was implemented in the qgsmapcanvas class

now there is no conflict, the zoom works well